# iOS Webkit readonly inputs selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, webkit

I have a site where i use readonly inputs. On the desktop I use js to select the input field on the first click.

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="select" value="Value to select">

$('.select').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
});
```

But in Safari for iOS I can't the select the input text at all (long tap on the text). 
Is there a way to make the text selectable?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this? Sometimes focus solves the problem, also perhaps the browser isn't aware that select() should trigger the event?:

```
$(this).focus().trigger('select');
```

Comment: no this isn't working. The input flashes for a short moment and nothing happens…